# Hyperledger fabric : Publish message between parties in a channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Scenario : A hyperledger-fabric blockchain with a channel and 2 parties. If `PartyB` wants to read info off the ledger which isn't readily available, is it possible for `PartyA` after updating the ledger notify `PartyB` to check query the ledger ? ( notify / publish within the blockchain )

I know it can be easily done external to the blockchain but is it possible to do it within the blockchain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that, is that party B would subscribe to [events](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peer_event_services.html?highlight=events) and parse them, and then decide if the data it is interested in, is in the blockchain or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks :D